# In javascript 5+'5' = '55' but 5+ + '5' = 10 why?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I know the first one is 55 because the number is read as a string due to '' but what happens to the second one. Can anyone explain? Thanks in advance.Btw '5' - - '5' = 10. what is wrong with javascript?

Comment: `+'5'` means that you're coercing the string to a number. You could also use `Number('5')`.

Comment: In programming, data types is an important concept.
To be able to operate on variables, it is important to know something about the type.
read this :
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

Comment: The double negative is also the the same as adding, but you're also converting the string to a number. So `5 - - '5'` is the same as `5 - (-'5')`, the one in parens gets coerced to a number `5 - - 5`, and the double negative is a plus sign: `5 + 5`. Also, watch this: https://archive.org/details/wat_destroyallsoftware

Answer (score 5):

In the second example, the string is being type coerced to a number first and then the two numbers are added. You might think of if like this:

```
5 + +'5' === 5 + (+'5')
```

+'5' is equal to the number 5.